# Trying to implement a rotating image on PySide6, the rotation is right but the image is jiggling

Tags: python, pyside6, pyqt6

I'm trying to have an image to be dynamically rotating depending on motors positions as for monitoring purposes and user interface interactions.
I used a sample image and simulated a constant rotation to do some tests.
I could get the signals and the rotation of the Pixmap with Qtransform right, but the image itself giggles a bit.

Resulting rotation: https://ibb.co/pwTjsbb

I did the following : set a fixed size for the Pixmap, aligned the image center, and unchecked scaled contents on QtDesigner.

The following code sample has two classes : the MainWindow with the image that has to rotate, and a "Rotation" class that simulates a constant motor rotation with a thread, because that's how i do the monitoring (check positions every 0.1seconds)

Here is the image 200x200 : https://ibb.co/c6FwB2F

```
import sys
import threading
import time

from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer, QSize
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

        self.img = "circle.png"
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.img)

        self.label.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)

        self.rotation = 0

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(Rotation.thread_refresh)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.rotate_pixmap)
        self.timer.start()

    def rotate_pixmap(self):
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.img)
        self.rotation = item.position

        transform = QtGui.QTransform().rotate(self.rotation)
        pixmap = pixmap.transformed(transform, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)


class Rotation:
    """
    This class simulates the position received by a motor in constant
    rotation, to get its data and apply it to the image rotation
    """
    break_thread = False
    thread_refresh = 0.1
    delta_angle = 1

    def __init__(self, position, speed):
        self.position = position
        self.speed = speed
        th = threading.Thread(target=self.start_rotation, args=())
        th.start()

    def angle_mapping(self):
        self.position = round(self.position % 360, 2)

    def define_speed(self):
        # speed in degrees/sec
        Rotation.delta_angle = Rotation.thread_refresh * self.speed
        pass

    def start_rotation(self):
        while not Rotation.break_thread:
            self.angle_mapping()
            self.define_speed()
            print(self.position)
            self.position += Rotation.delta_angle
            time.sleep(Rotation.thread_refresh)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    item = Rotation(0, 10)  # Initial angle, speed in degrees/sec

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()

    window.show()
    app.exec()

    Rotation.break_thread = True
```

Also it's my first post, please let me know if i can further improve my contributions

Edit : I might just be using the wrong tool to do a dynamic rotation, if you know any better libraries that can be implemented with Pyside6 to answer my purpose, please let me know

Edit 2 : Added a QTimer as recommended, and provided the picture used

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First of all, widgets are not thread safe, so do ***NOT*** do that, you were just lucky enough to not get issues with that, but it's unsafe and unreliable, it could just fail on somebody else's computer (or even your own at some point, depending on circumstances). So, for that threading is also completely useless, just use QTimer. That said, the "giggling" is probably caused by a misalignment of the circle in the original image *and* the way the rotation is applied to the pixmap, so please provide that file too.

Comment: Hi musicamante, I actually used the thread to simulate to motor datas received. I didnt know about QTimer, i'll improve the code and post it with more details once it's ready

Answer (score 0):

The given approach is not a good one, because it completely rotates the *whole* pixmap and, as the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpixmap.html#transformed) (emphasis mine):

> The transformation transform is internally adjusted to compensate for unwanted translation; i.e. the pixmap produced is **the smallest pixmap that contains all the transformed points of the original pixmap**.

The result is clear once you remove the `setFixedSize()` line and use a different color for the background:

[image: Screenshot of the rotated image without restraints]

Even if you've set the alignment of the label, that cannot completely solve the issue, for the following reaons:

- the source image is not perfectly centered;
- since the image is always adjusted to the minimum representation of the source pixels, you get a final image that is a "bounding rectangle" of the rotated square (as the image above, the *red* square);
- even if the source square uses integer sizes, that bounding rectangle would have floating point coordinates: for instance, a 100x100 square rotated by 1° results in a bounding rectangle that has sides of ~101.73 pixels, for 2° it's ~103.43, about 105 for 3°, etc;
- image sizes are integer values which means that the image will be adjusted to the closest "biggest" bounding rect, which would probably be sized 102 pixels for 1° and 104 for 2° and 105 for 3°;
- like images, widgets also work with integer values for coordinates, and since you used a center alignment for the label, Qt will try to adapt its center by rounding the computation; for obvious reasons, a widget sized with odd coordinates in a container using even sizes (or vice versa) will align it as well as it can, but it will *never* be perfectly centered, and since the size changes continuously with odd and even values, the alignment continuously changes along with it;

Consider all the above aspects, and you'll get your "giggling".

There are two options, then.
Note that in the following examples I'll use a QThread, which is normally more appropriate and flexible to work with Qt objects

### Custom widget

Use a custom widget, override the painting and apply the transformation matrix to the painter; since drawing is always based on floating point coordinates, the rotation will be consistent. Note that in order to align the rotation to the center of the image, three steps are required: first translate to the transformation origin (the center), then apply the rotation, and finally reverse the translation to the beginning:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class RotationWidget(QWidget):
    position = rotation = 0
    def __init__(self, image='circle.png'):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = QPixmap(image)
        self.setFixedSize(self.image.size())
        self.transform = QTransform()
        half = self.image.size() / 2
        self.tX = half.width()
        self.tY = half.height()

    def setPosition(self, pos):
        if self.position != pos:
            self.rotation = pos - self.position
        else:
            self.rotation = 0
        self.position = pos
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(qp.Antialiasing)
        qp.setRenderHint(qp.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        self.transform.translate(self.tX, self.tY)
        self.transform.rotate(self.rotation)
        self.transform.translate(-self.tX, -self.tY)
        qp.setTransform(self.transform)
        qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.image)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.rotationWidget = RotationWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.rotationWidget)

    def positionChanged(self, pos):
        self.rotationWidget.setPosition(pos)


class Rotation(QThread):
    positionChanged = pyqtSignal(object)
    delta_angle = 1
    thread_refresh = 0.1
    
    def __init__(self, position, speed):
        super().__init__()
        self.position = position
        self.speed = speed

    def run(self):
        while True:
            diff = self.thread_refresh * self.speed
            self.position = round((self.position + diff) % 360, 2)
            self.positionChanged.emit(self.position)
            self.msleep(self.thread_refresh * 1000)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    item = Rotation(0, 10)
    item.positionChanged.connect(window.positionChanged)

    window.show()
    item.start()
    app.exec()
```

### Use a Graphics Item

While a bit more complex, the [Graphics View framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) is designed to allow such transformations by default, and with very good performance even with thousands of items.

For very simple cases like this, it's actually quite easy to implement the above, which doesn't even require a subclass:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(QSize(200, 200))
        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.rotationItem = scene.addPixmap(QPixmap('circle.png'))
        # set the origin for the transformation at the center of the pixmap
        self.rotationItem.setTransformOriginPoint(
            self.rotationItem.boundingRect().center())
        # ensure that the transformation is always antialiased
        self.rotationItem.setTransformationMode(Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        self.view = QGraphicsView(scene)
        self.view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.view.setFrameShape(0)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

    def positionChanged(self, pos):
        self.rotationItem.setRotation(pos)
```

Comment: It's working fine as intended, thanks!
Being new to coding I've had a hard time understanding the logic behind the widget method, but I've finally figured it out despite a few misunderstandings I'd like you to clarify if it's ok :
- I understood we create a variable with the pyqtSignal function to emit the position to window.positionChanged, who then sends it to RotationWidget.setPosition. Why do we have to take this detour?
- How is the paintEvent function called ? I found out it's a QWidget function but I don't understand how to call is made internally, is it linked to the self.update() ?

Comment: As for the Graphics Item method I didnt figure out how to implement it

Comment: @Fab That's not a requirement, but it's also for more appropriate modularity, had you created the `item` inside the main window class, you could've connected it directly. It's usually better to avoid accessing "sub-level" objects and leave their "parents" act as proxies. Note that `positionChanged` is not just a variable, but a signal, which is an essential part of Qt and the only thing that allows communicating with objects in different threads. `paintEvent` is called by Qt, and can **never** be directly called programmatically: it's an *event handler*. It's possible to *schedule* its call ->

Comment: @Fab by calling `update()` or requesting an immediate `repaint()`, but the function is still not called directly, as Qt calls it only whenever it believes it necessary. The Graphics View framework is as powerful as complex. If you plan on using complex graphics, with multiple items (possibly in the order of hundreds or thousands) or "free" movement, that's the correct choice, but it takes a lot of patience and experience in order to understand it. As always, the documentation is the starting point for everything.

Comment: It's all clear now
Thank you so much for your time and sharing musicamente